# Secured client server requests

Tags: java, android, authentication, client-server

I am looking for some guidelines as to how to secure requests from android client to server

How can i prevent un autenthic (users which initiate requests not from the android app) requests to be accepted and processed by the server?

Waybe generate token at user registration and use it somehow at each call?

My server is a lite instance and performance is top issue in the implementation of the server client communication.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Does this need to be 100% secure or do you only want to secure your server against unwanted requests/spam?

Comment: Just need to protect from unwanted requests

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google Cloud Messaging as a via medium to make sure messages that reach your server are from the app, without getting too involved in details. Check the documentation here:
https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Or else, as you said, create a unique id on registration and send it back to the client. Store it at both client and server. Now with each request from the client, add an extra field in the request and send the id also. Check this id serverside and make sure it is valid (this check could eventually become heavy on time).

Comment: How does it prevent from people who trace device calls from using this id?

Comment: It probably wouldn't. But then again, if you have access to the message data, *any* identification method is hackable, right? Maybe put your id in a misleading field, like 'garbage':<your_unique_id>